# Facebook Share only works if user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-sharer

I'm hoping this isn't a duplicate, but I haven't seen this explained before. I've got a very basic Facebook Share implementation that I'm trying to use:

`<a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="http://www.google.com"></a>
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
        type="text/javascript">
</script>`

**The problem is**: the FIRST time I click my "share" button, it prompts me to login to facebook. When I login in, it takes me straight to my news feed and does not show the link I'm trying to share. But if I login, close the window and then re-click my "share" button, it shows the link I'm trying to share.

Is there something I'm missing from my code? I'm using IE9 if that makes a difference.

**EDIT:** It appears to work fine in Chrome, but does NOT work in Safari either.

**EDIT 2**: After trying to use Juicy Scripter's solution with the Feed Dialog, I am now having trouble with the following code. After I'm prompted to Login to Facebook, I get a red error message that just says "An error has occurred, please try again later." Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong with the following code? Also, is there a "best practice" in getting my link to be the actual Facebook button (like it was for the Share option?)

`<a  onclick='postToFacebook(); return false;'>FB post</a>`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function postToFacebook() {
            FB.init();
            FB.ui({ method: 'feed', link: "http://www.google.com" });
        }
    </script>`
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted by other answer [Share Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) is deprecated so it's better to avoid it.

Use [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed) to publish content on user's feed. For general purposes next code may be used to share current page link (consult [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed) for additional parameters):

```
FB.ui({method: 'feed', link: document.location.href});
```

Comment: @lhan16, just be sure to call [JS-SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) [`FB.init`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/) before ;)

Comment: @lhan16, You should call `FB.init` with your application id like this: `FB.init({appId: APPLCIATION_ID})` (see [JS SDK documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) for full list of parameters). There is a *note* on JS-SDK documentation: *"Please note following: The JS SDK requires the fb-root element in order to load properly and a to call FB.init is required to correctly initialize the SDK with your app ID."*

Answer (score 1):

I tried alternate ways to invoke that share dialog: using `FB.ui({"method": "stream.share", "u": "http://www.google.com"});` and via direct url `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com`.

They all gave me the poor user experience of taking me to my news feed after logging into Facebook in Safari (I don't have IE9 handy, but I assume it's the same).

I don't think there's anything you can do about it.

Also, Facebook has deprecated the share button in favor of the Like button.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/:

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

I tested the logged out Like button experience in Safari.  I click Like, it opens a popup to login to Facebook, after logging in the popup is closed but I have to click the Like button again for it to count.

Comment: Hmm. Is there a different way to post links to a website on your wall? or is that idea in general being deprecated? I'm just looking at doing the equivalent of tweeting a link on Twitter.

Comment: @lhan16 The feed dialog is probably what you want - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ - which you can call via `FB.ui({"method": "feed", ... more options ...});`

Comment: Oops, just saw the accepted answer, so you already know this.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was Safari would not prepopulate the dialog with content after the user logged in. I used the **Direct URL** method of the FB feed dialog and everything seems to be working in Safari now.

More info [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).

Thanks to all who answered above.